# Is it possible to make a vegan chocolate mint cake?

Tags: recipe-request

I've requested a grasshopper cake or a chocolate mint cake for my birthday.

Is it possible to make such a cake vegan or even vegetarian?

If so, how?

Comment: Do you have a current recipe that you're hoping to convert, or have you looked for a vegan grasshopper cake recipe? Vegan cake is quite doable and mint and chocolate are both available in vegan versions, so I'm not sure what you're looking for :)

Comment: @Erica I didn’t know about either version,sorry. Mostly I’m going a vegan version that everyone can enjoy.

Comment: A lot of recipes in Google results: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vegan+chocolate+mint+cake%22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, it's possible.

A quick [internet search for vegan chocolate mint cake](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=vegan+chocolate+mint+cake) reveals this is a common choice and there are many recipes you or your friend can follow. I have tried [this one](https://www.brokefoodies.com/vegan-chocolate-mint-cake/) myself and I am pleased, but that is of course subjective.

Making cakes could be somewhat involved if you are not into cooking, but this is not different from non-vegan recipes. Alternatively, you could try to find a bakery that sells such cake in your city.